# Conflict between baseUrl and node_modules when importing

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, stripe-payments

I have a TS project with the following configuration:

**tsconfig.json (partial)**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

I have a dependency on the `stripe` NPM package:

```js
{
  // ...
  "dependencies": {
    "stripe": "^8.45.0",
  }
}
```

Then I have the following files:

```
src/routes/payments/index.ts
src/stripe/index.ts
```

I am having some trouble with imports in `src/routes/payments/index.ts`. I want to import the `stripe` library, not my own code.

This works:

```
// Uses me the 'Stripe' constructor which is the default export from the package
const stripe = require('stripe')('KEY');
```

This does not work:

```
import Stripe from 'stripe';
const stripe = new Stripe('KEY');
```

I get the following error:

```
Module '"PROJECT/src/stripe/index"' has no default export.
```

How do I disambiguate and tell TS I want to use `stripe` from node_modules?

Comment: Can you provide an example project? I have used local module names that mirrored installed packages a number of times and have never had issues. Your `tsconfig` also looks fine to me, although I have seen `src/**/*` more often than just `src`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you try to update the **tsconfig.json** file like this:

```json
{
 "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "node_modules/*",
        "src/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @NeNaD I am interested on this question. Can you please provide an explanation about your answer? Thanks.

Comment: Basically, for every import check in `node_modules` and in `scr` folder. With current implementation, I think it will check only in `scr` folder.